# Corda - Notary Vault table and uniqueness

Tags: corda

I have a question on the NODE_NOTARY_COMMIT_LOG table used to record the notary transactions. My first (bad) assumption was that the TRANSACTION_ID was unique in this table, but it appears that this is not the case - when I found two tables entries with the same TRANSACTION_ID and CONSUMING_TRANSACTION_ID, but the CONSUMING_INPUT_INDEX was incremented, and the OUTPUT_INDEX was also different (the opposite to the consuming input index). could someone explain to me how this works and how to determine uniqueness in the table - Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The NODE_NOTARY_COMMIT_LOG table is effectively a map of state reference to consuming transaction id. The column pair (TRANSACTION_ID, OUTPUT_INDEX) identifies the state: it's the id of the transaction that *issued* the state, and the state's position in outputs.

CONSUMING_TRANSACTION_ID and CONSUMING_INPUT_INDEX specify which transaction consumed the state, and the state's position in the inputs.

Note that since Corda 3.0 the CONSUMING_INPUT_INDEX is no longer recorded.